# Memory leak in recursive function with reference

Tags: php, recursion, memory-leaks

I got this following code. It's a system to get items and all the children of the children of the children .... of the item. Well, I use a recursive function to do it:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

require_once 'config.php';

function getItems($parent) {
    global $db;

    $itemsStmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `parent_id` = ?');
    $itemsStmt->execute(array($parent));
    return $itemsStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function addToArray($items, &$array) {    
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $child = $item['child_id'];
        $indexer = $item['id'];

        $array[$indexer] = array('children' => array());
        $array[$indexer]['definition'] = $item;

        if ($child)
        {
            addToArray(getItems($child), $array[$indexer]['children']);
        }
    }
}

$array = array();

addToArray(getButtons(1), $array);

echo json_encode($array);
```

The items table looks like this:

```
id INT PK AI
title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
child_id INT
parent_id INT
```

The child_id is used for the parent_id of the children (so you don't have to use a query to get the children if they're not exist).

Now, it kind of works. But if I add an item with the following data:

```
NULL
DELETEMELATER
0
2
```

I get a memory limit error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42 bytes)
```

Which is on this line:

```
return $itemsStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Your first function is called `getItems` while you are calling `getButtons`

Comment: Sorry forgot to change it. But it still happens.

Comment: parent_id belongs to parent's `id` column or `child` column? In case of `id` you need to change `getButtons($child)` to `getButtons($indexer)`

Comment: I already know the problem. At my saving .php file, I changed the child_id of ID 1 to 1. Parent_id 1 is the group. So when looping item with id 1, it will add the parents and all the children again. Over and over again, because parent_id 1 are groups and those all have children. ID 1 is a child. Just a dumb mistake of me.

Comment: could you increase the memory_limit in php.ini of your server? for a single script you can use : ini_set('memory_limit' '-1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is with your db `structure` and its `data` as you have and `parent_id` and `child_id` and if there will be an row which has and parent_id and child_id which are same you will have infinite loop of recursion and that is why you got out of memory exception, you have to fix your data in db or upgrate table strucvcure to have only parent_id and control your structure with it

**Examples of infinite loop in your db structure case**

1) item1 parent is item2 and item2 child is item1

2) if item2 is parent for item1 and item1 is parent for item3 but item3 is parent for item2

Comment: Yes, I found that out. Just a dumb mistake of me.